# How do I connect my 20 year old hard drive and copy data?

Tags: hard-drive

*It’s a Dell Inspiron laptop, at least 15 years old.*

Is there a adapter or an external hard drive enclosure I can use?  The one's I found in Amazon seems to have a different set of pins:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you can probably pull that pin connector at the back & it's like a IDE/PATA (40-pin?) common connector

Comment: Indeed top right shows 32GB IDE

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA Don't be surprised if the drive is unreadable

Comment: https://a.co/d/d7cJuUS

Comment: You have an ATA/IDE HDD. There are USB adapters that allow you to mount such a drive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which kind of hard disk is this? (7 cm × 9,5 cm, 48 pins)](https://superuser.com/questions/1212574/which-kind-of-hard-disk-is-this-7-cm-%c3%97-9-5-cm-48-pins)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a laptop HDD – as people writing their answers via comments mention, those very often had an adapter from regular 44-pin laptop IDE to the laptop manufacturer's proprietary "easier to plug" port stuck on them. You can carefully remove the adapter, by which I mean **very carefully** peel it off from **both** ends at the same time, as those pins *will* bend sideways if you try to tilt it off from just one end. (Which is one of the reasons they had those adapters, really.)

Once you do that, you'll have a regular 44-pin "laptop IDE" connector (physically smaller than desktop 40-pin ports).

There are plenty of USB adapters for this (often with the larger desktop IDE on one side, smaller laptop IDE on the other).

While a 15-year-old HDD should be working perfectly fine, it's probably a better idea to image the disk first (using Disk2vhd or whatever), then extract files out of the image – mainly to avoid the "Give access to this folder?" Windows prompts that would otherwise cause a lot of writes back to the HDD, and as a general precaution in case the HDD happens to be on its last spin.

On Linux I'd suggest having `ddrescue` installed so that you could make a 1:1 copy of the disk if it's having difficulties reading some parts. (I don't know if it's available for Windows, but the raw image it creates can be later turned into a .VHD for browsing in Windows.)